# When is the best time to list a domain name / website in Google Analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I have just booked a domain name and it has only one page showing my Office Address (only text...no links) which I have already listed in Google Analytics after opeing my Google Analytics Account.

Was this a correct action or mistimed to list a domain name / web site which has only one page?

When is the best time to list a domain name /website in Google Analytics account?

(Please note that I have completed Goolge Analytics Verification process also>)

Comment: Why would you think it makes a difference?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I think having a single page hosted for a domain name and inviting google to keep tab on this web site will lead google to index this site with only one page. After that we add few more pages but we never know that when the google will reindex the site.

Comment: You are not "inviting Google" to do anything. Google search doesn't use data from Analytics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no "best time" when it comes to using GA, as it depends on you as a site owner, because you are the only one who can decide when you can actually use the collected data about your traffic and visitors behavior.

However there is no harm collecting early stage data which comes before launching the site, they won't held much value but they can easily be ignored and/or totally erased from your account.

Anyway, having "goals" to achieve is a good sign for you to start collecting and using GA data.

**Long story short**, there is no "*best time*" when it comes to collecting data, but "*best time*" to use that data is when you have some goals to achieve.

Another question that came across my mind when i read yours is "Does GA collected data make difference in your SEO / affect your ranking?"

According to Matt it doesn't ([YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgBw9tbAQhU&list=PLgKvOuBLxQDLesqj3A3_JfDs-ihX_yhFm&index=5))

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with adding google analytics installed in a web-site that is only with one page.

If you get visitors to a site, it will log them. And while this information may not be useful at the moment. You may find it useful later on.